# Keycloak Custom Decorator for Resources

Tags: nestjs, keycloak

Is there any way to customize decorator of resources i-e @Resource() Decorator in nest-key cloak-connect.

In this @Resource() decorator we have to pass name of resource in string,
I have tried it with hard coded value but I want to make it dynamic
example:

@Resource('my bag') // name of resource

and I want to make it dynamic like =>
@Resource(`${Resource-Name}`) // It will pick resource name automatically or is there any way to pass resource name here in that variable or function?

any guidance will be appreciated.